# regex to exclude certain characters from string but preserve full string

Tags: regex, string

Given text which contains braces `{}`, I need to extract all text excluding braces but including newlines and preserve the string.  Sample text:

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. {Maecenas congue massa.} Endus.
> Pellentesque habitant {morbi} tristique senectus et turpis egestas. 
> Mauris et orci.
> ```

I have used  `\w(.*|\n)*`, which preserves braces, and string duplicates original. To remove braces I tried negating `\w([^{}]|\n)*`. But this `regex` breaks the string at each brace:

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. 
> Maecenas congue massa.
> Endus.[CR][LF]Pellentesque habitant 
> morbi
> ```

Any ideas how to skip the braces and preserve one string are appreciated. I cannot add any code to strip or concatenate strings. This must be `regex` only.

Comment: It is rather unclear. Do you mean [`[^{}]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b&i=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2c+elit.+%7bMaecenas+congue+massa.%7d+Endus.%0d%0aPellentesque+habitant+%7bmorbi%7d+tristique+senectus+et+turpis+egestas.+%0d%0aMauris+et+orci.)? Note that if you want to match a discontinuous text within one match operation, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

`/[{}]+/` is what you want to exclude. So this works for me in perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. {Maecenas congue massa.} Endus.
Pellentesque habitant {morbi} tristique senectus et turpis egestas. 
 et orci.";


(my $result = $string) =~ s/[{}]+//g;

print $result;
```

(you don't need to mess with capture groups as you are keeping everything else)

*update*

You comment that your implementation is in .Net (not mentioned in the question). I cannot test against .Net (i am osx/unix only) so this is only a blind suggestion. I'm not quite sure how replacement patterns are configured in .Net. But the basic idea is to search for 0 or more of any character that is NOT { or }, capture that, followed by uncaptured { or }, followed by 0 or more of any character that is NOT { or }. That should retain your newlines.

Something similar to this...

```
  string pattern = "([[^{}]*)[{}]([^{}]*)";
  string replacement = "\1\2";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input,  pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: Your regex simplifies mine but works the same. The string breaks at the first brace so I only get "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit." The regex is implemented in a .Net application, and i am trying to avoid any application code changes (new release, etc).  I have been using Expresso for testing and it works the same as the app. Maybe there is not solution?

Comment: The update works in a similar manner to the initial suggestion, which is what I decided to use. We have no way in the application to do a replacment or substitution as in the update. Removing the braces will eventually be a C# code change. Thanks for your suggestions.